# select from multiple tables with linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `Category` like this:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string catName { get; set; }
public List<string> subCat { get; set; }
```

And I have 2 tables, `tblCategory` and `tblSubCategory`.

I want to select all categories and the subcategories under each category. I am trying the code below, but I get the same result for all the categories, even if some categories doesn't have any subCategories they still get the hole list of subCategories.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public static List<Category> getCategoryList()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new LinqToDBAwkoDataContext())
        {
            var list = from c in db.tblCategories
                       select new Category
                            {
                               id = c.CatId,
                               catName = c.CatName,
                               subCat = subCategoriesByCatId(db)
                           };
            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error has occurred");
    }            
}

private static List<string> subCategoriesByCatId(LinqToDBAwkoDataContext db)
{
    var list = from s in db.tblSubCategories
               join c in db.tblCategories on s.CatId equals c.CatId
               where s.CatId == c.CatId
               select s.SubCatName;
    return list.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Your first hint that something is wrong should be that your `subCategoriesByCatId` method doesn't actually accept a category id. You need to accept a category ID in that method and use it in the `where` clause of the subcategory query. Also, you don't need a join in the subcategories query.

Comment: I see the mistake now. Put your answer as an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes. First you select all category and subcategories in `subCategoriesByCatId` methos. You must pass `CatId` to this method. But then it produces a sub query. I dont think you want that. Use a simple join. Second, You call `ToList` in `subCategoriesByCatId` method. This causes a round trip to database for each row in `Categories` table.

```
public static List<Category> getCategoryList()
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new LinqToDBAwkoDataContext())
        {
            var list = from c in db.tblCategories
                       join s in db.tblSubCategories
                       select new Category
                       {
                           id = c.CatId,
                           catName = c.CatName,
                           subCat = s.SubCatName
                       };
            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("An error has occured");
    }            
}
```

Comment: If I don't return list.ToList() what else should I return.? and I can't select subCat=s.SubCatName in getCategoryList(). That gives me error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collection.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: You can get what you want with the above code. Or may be I didn't understand what you want. If so please explaine.